# Helm template is not compatible to values.yaml structure

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following ingress.yaml:

```
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host }}                 // row 31
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . | quote }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And the following values to feed this template:

```
  hosts:
    host: "app.example.com"
    paths:
      - "/api"
      - "/oauth"

  tls:
    - secretName: "example-tls"
      hosts:
        - "*.app.example.com"
        - "dev.example.com"
```

When I run "helm install" it fails on:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: templates/ingress.yaml:31:15:
> executing "templates/ingress.yaml" at <.host>: can't evaluate field
> host in type interface {}

So for me it looks like hosts must be a list, not a dictionary (because of **range** instruction). So I convert it:

```
  hosts:
    - host: "app.example.com"
      paths:
        - "/api"
        - "/oauth"
```

But in this case I get:

> warning: destination for hosts is a table. Ignoring non-table value
> [map[host:app.example.com paths:[/api /oauth]]]

and the same error as above in addition.

How to make it working?

**UPDATE 1**

Values:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true

  rules:
    - host: c1.app.example.com
      paths:
        - /api
        - /oauth
    - host: c2.app.example.com
      paths:
        - /api
        - /oauth
  tls:
    - secretName: "example-tls"
      hosts:
        - "*.app.example.com"
        - "dev.example.com"
```

Template:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.rules }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . | quote }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I understood that problem was not in code but in command line. I fed with string instead of array.

> helm template ... --set ingress.hosts.host=c1.app.example.com ...

I will try to figure out how to provide multiple values and update it here.

**UPDATE 3**

I erased data from values:

```
ingress:
  enabled: false

  rules:
    - host:

  tls:
    - secretName:
      hosts: []
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @HelloWorld I just placed UPDATE 3. This was a solution.

Comment: Please provide the answer as an actutal answer, not update to the question. Let the question be the question and use answer to post answers, don't mix them together. It's hard to see that this is the solution. After adding the answer please mark it as accepted. Thank You

Comment: @HelloWorld done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The problem was in mismatch of ingress template structure and command line arguments that I have provided for params override.

This is the proper fit of **command line arguments**:

```
helm upgrade <some other options here>
--values ./values.yaml
--set ingress.enabled=True
--set ingress.tls[0].hosts[0]=app.example.com
--set ingress.tls[0].secretName=example-tls
--set ingress.rules[0].host=app.example.com
```

That populates **values.yaml**:

```
ingress:
  enabled: false

  rules:
    - host:

  tls:
    - secretName:
      hosts: []
```

For ingress **template**:

```
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - secretName: {{ .secretName }}
      hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.rules }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /api
          backend:
            serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
            servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The template is looking for `.Values.ingress.hosts`, whereas in your displayed values there is no `ingress` prefix. And as `range` operator is being used, we should have a *list of dictionary*.

Also, before doing a `helm install`, it would be good to run `helm template` just to make sure the the YAML definitions are rendered correctly.

Considering the below content in `values.yaml`:

```yaml
--- 
ingress: 
  hosts: 
    - 
      host: app1.example.com
      paths: 
        - /api
        - /oauth
    - 
      host: app2.example.com
      paths: 
        - /api1
        - /authz
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - "*.app.example.com"
      - "dev.example.com"
      secretName: "example-tls"
```

Running `helm template` command results in (I have defined `serviceName` as haproxy, and `servicePort` as 8080 for illustration):

```yaml
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.app.example.com"
        - "dev.example.com"
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: app1.example.com                 // row 31
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/api"
            backend:
              serviceName: haproxy
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: "/oauth"
            backend:
              serviceName: haproxy
              servicePort: 8080
    - host: app2.example.com                 // row 31
      # similar output for app2.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you. I have ingress (just have cut it as redundant for the case). In UPDATE 1 I've improved according to what you said. Still no luck. By the way I noticed that naming is important. When I renamed "hosts" to "rules" it skipped to "paths" part. Please take a look at UPDATE 1.

Comment: Well, UPDATE 1 is not relevant. UPDATE 2 now :)

Comment: Well `--set` is another way to provide values to the template. You can pass it with `-f values.yaml` as well. Both should work the same.